# Can't install displaylink driver with current kernel

Tags: 16.04, drivers, displaylink

I tried downloading [this driver](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu) to make an external usb-c dock with displaylink work. Unfortunately installing it I get this error message

```
    sudo ./displaylink-driver-1.2.65.run [sudo] password di federico: 
    Verifying archive integrity... All good.
    Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 1.2.65 100% 
    DisplayLink Linux Software 1.2.65 install script called: install
    Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
    Installing
    Configuring EVDI DKMS module
    Registering EVDI kernel module with DKMS
    Building EVDI kernel module with DKMS
    ERROR (code 3): Failed to build evdi/1.2.65. Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.2.65/build/make.log for details..
```

[here the make log](http://pastebin.com/tqMHTNWD)

on the displaylink forum they [linked me this](https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/commit/f128d9502b5f74d384427bdb43719d1b6e9a7594) but I don't know how to use it (tried make & make install, tried putting it into the .run of the driver)

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: $ uname -r 4.9.0-040900-generic

Comment: lsb_release -a
LSB Version: core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

Comment: thanks to cristian_c & gigirock on #ubuntu-it irc I'v got a hold on this https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian ....unfortunately I can't find sources for  4.9.0-040900