# where can I find linux-sources 4.9.5 deb package?

Tags: 16.04, kernel

In the [mainline repo for 4.9.5](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.9.5/) only linux-headers and linux-image are available, where can I find linux-sources (and linux-tools) ?

Comment: Isnt it already there in your posted link [Here](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git)

Comment: What do you need them for? It you really need the source, you know where to get it.

Comment: @Pilot6 for this http://askubuntu.com/questions/874558/cant-install-displaylink-driver-with-current-kernel

Comment: @suraj yes, but that would mean cloning the git, applying the patches etcetc

Comment: @suraj also, tried to use git but dunno why it compiled 4.10rc5 O.o

Comment: -sources and -tools will appear when the package is released into the Ubuntu repos for pre-release testing. The PPA is for pre-pre-release testing. Only skilled kernel testers (who file bugs) and git gurus should be playing with those packages in the PPA

Comment: But yakkety yak will come with 4.10! :(